# Why does Spark application work in spark-shell but fail with "org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable" in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

With the purpose of save a file (delimited by |) into a DataFrame, I have developed the next code:

```
val file = sc.textFile("path/file/")
val rddFile = file.map(a => a.split("\\|")).map(x => ArchivoProcesar(x(0), x(1), x(2), x(3))

val dfInsumos = rddFile.toDF()
```

My case class used for the creation of my DataFrame is defined as followed:

```
case class ArchivoProcesar(nombre_insumo: String, tipo_rep: String, validado: String, Cargado: String)
```

I have done some functional tests using **spark-shell**, and my code works fine, generating the DataFrame correctly. But when I executed my program into eclipse, it throws me the next error:

[image]

Is it something missing inside my scala class that I'm using and running with eclipse. Or what could be the reason that my functions works correctly at the **spark-shell** but not in my eclipse app?

Regards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark job is failed due to java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SparkContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23605542/spark-job-is-failed-due-to-java-io-notserializableexception-org-apache-spark-sp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your case class must have public scope. You can't have ArchivoProcesar inside a class

Comment: It *may* help the author, but there is no explanation and the source problem is not in nested case class

Answer (score 1):

> I have done some functional tests using spark-shell, and my code works fine, generating the DataFrame correctly.

That's because `spark-shell` takes care of creating an instance of `SparkContext` for you. `spark-shell` then makes sure that references to `SparkContext` are not from "sensitive places".

> But when I executed my program into eclipse, it throws me the next error:

Somewhere in your Spark application you hold a reference to `org.apache.spark.SparkContext` that is **not** serializable and so holds your Spark computation back from being serialized and send across the wire to executors.

As [@T. Gawęda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5811800/t-gaw%C4%99da) has mentioned in a comment:

> I think that `ArchivoProcesar` is a nested class and as a nested class has a reference to the outer class that has a property of type `SparkContext`

So while copying the code from `spark-shell` to Eclipse you *have* added some additional lines that you don't show thinking that they are not necessary which happens to be quite the contrary. Find any places where you create and reference `SparkContext` and you will find the root cause of your issue.

I can see that the Spark processing happens inside `ValidacionInsumos` class that `main` method uses. I think the affecting method is `LeerInsumosAValidar` that does `map` transformation and that's where you should seek the answer.

Comment: It would be great to add this suggestion. Up vote from my side :)