# How to read file names from column in DataFrame to process using SparkContext.textFile?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I'm so new using Spark and I'm so stuck with this issue:

From a DataFrame that I have created; called `reportesBN`, I want to get the value of a field, in order to use it to get a TextFile of a specific route. And after that, give to that file a specific process.

I have developed this code, but its not working:

```
reportesBN.foreach { 
      x => 
        val file = x(0)
        val insumo = sc.textFile(s"$file")

        val firstRow = insumo.first.split("\\|", -1)

        // Get values of next rows
        val nextRows = insumo.mapPartitionsWithIndex { (idx, iter) => if (idx == 0) iter.drop(1) else iter }

        val dfNextRows = nextRows.map(a => a.split("\\|")).map(x=> BalanzaNextRows(x(0), x(1),
          x(2), x(3), x(4))).toDF() 

        val validacionBalanza = new RevisionCampos(sc)
        validacionBalanza.validacionBalanza(firstRow, dfNextRows)
}
```

The error log indicates that it is because of serialization.

```
7/06/28 18:55:45 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from textFile at ValidacionInsumos.scala:56
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
```

Is this problem caused by the Spark Context (`sc`) that is inside the foreach?

Is there another way to implement this?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A very similar question you asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44792350/1305344) and that's that same issue - you cannot use `SparkContext` inside a RDD transformation or action. In this case, you use `sc.textFile(s"$file")` inside `reportesBN.foreach` which as you said is a `DataFrame`:

> From a DataFrame that I have created; called `reportesBN`

You should rewrite your transformation to take a file from the DataFrame and read it afterwards.

```
// This is val file = x(0)
// I assume that the column name is `files`
val files = reportesBN.select("files").as[String].collectAsList
```

Once you have the collection of files to process, you execute the code in your block.

```
files.foreach { 
      x => ...
}
```