# sparkSession.sparkContext is null with local spark cluster

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch, rdd

I have created a local Spark cluster and a spark session from it like below

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf(true).setAppName("test").setMaster("local[8]")

val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate()
```

Using it I have also successfully created Dummy dataframes to use in my test scala App

```
val dummy: DataFrame = sparkSession.createDataFrame(Seq(
  ("BABY", "videos", "0.5"),
  ("APPLIANCES AND STORAGE", "audios", "0.6")
).toDF("dept", "type", "weight")
```

Later I have created an object Item and I am trying to write it to Elastic Search like below

```
val elasticItemRDD = sparkSession.sparkContext.makeRDD(Seq(Item))
    EsSpark.saveToEs(elasticItemRDD, esIndexNType, Map("es.mapping.id" -> "itemid"))
```

This is giving me a null pointer exception while accessing sparkContext from my sparkSession. I have tried

```
sparkSession.createDataset(Seq(Item)).rdd
```

which won't give me this null pointer error but some other MatchError. I like to make my sparkContext.makeRDD work so I can write to ElasticSearch. What might be the reason for this NullPointerException? Am I missing something?

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
val sparkVersion = "2.2.0"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-hive_2.11" % sparkVersion,
  "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11" % "5.5.1"
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is that SparkContext isn't available in my map function closure. It is available only for driver functions and not for worker tasks.

[Spark job is failed due to java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SparkContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23605542/spark-job-is-failed-due-to-java-io-notserializableexception-org-apache-spark-sp)