# Using Spark newAPIHadoopFile (FileInputFormat) met NotSerializableException

Tags: apache-spark, serialization, hadoop2

I'm using spark 2.1.0 and hadoop 2.7.3.

I was trying to use newAPIHadoopFile, very simple code in just one class with main method:

```scala
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("test").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
    val sparkContext = spark.sparkContext
    val sparkConf = sparkContext.getConf
    val file = "src/main/resources/chat.csv"
    sparkConf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
    sparkContext.getConf.registerKryoClasses(Array(
      Class.forName("org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable"),
      Class.forName("org.apache.hadoop.io.Text")
    ));
    sparkConf.set("spark.kryo.classesToRegister", "org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable, org.apache.hadoop.io.Text")
    val rdd = sparkContext.newAPIHadoopFile(file, classOf[KeyValueTextInputFormat], classOf[Text], classOf[Text])
    rdd.collect().foreach(println)
```

I checked many posts in StackOverflow, but still got error:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text

Serialization stack:

    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, value:   How about Italian?"})

    - field (class: scala.Tuple2, name: _1, type: class java.lang.Object)

    - object (class scala.Tuple2, (  How about Italian?"},))

    - element of array (index: 0)

    - array (class [Lscala.Tuple2;, size 3)

    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
```

Edit: content of chat.csv:

```
{from:"Gert", to:"Melissa", message:"Want to have dinner?"}
{from:"Melissa", to:"Gert", message:"Ok\
How about Italian?"}
```

Comment: Can you paste code here the from starting with class name and all?

Comment: All code are here.. except main method declaration and import.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running the same code you provided with spark 1.6.0 in my machine and it is working fine(I used tab separated file in HDFS). What version of spark/hadoop you are using?

In some cases(may be with the lower versions) Text do not implements serializable. So before collecting it map to String and try again,

something like below, the result of newAPIhadoopFile will be a tuple of key value,

`rdd.map(x=>(x._1.toString,x._2.toString)).collect().foreach(println)`

try this.

ref:[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071152/aparch-spark-notserializableexception-org-apache-hadoop-io-text)

Comment: I'm using spark 2.1.0 and hadoop 2.7.3, I'll also add this info to question. thanks.

Comment: And have check that post already, still not work with spark 2.1.0.

Comment: so what your input file has?

Comment: Just few lines, I added in question. Thanks for your support.

Comment: the same content running for me! have you used the map I suggested?

Comment: hm... don't know why it doesn't work for me, need to spend some more time. anyway,  thanks very much for your help.

Comment: You r welcome! Let me know once you find the solution.